# How can I optimize the following code which is contained in this function

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

Actually I am using a function rem() to find the maximum possible integer present in the list?Here the list l contains n elements,from 1 to n.We will do this following operation till n-1 times:
Here I am removing the first two elements of list, X and Y,then I am adding  this value (X+Y+(X*Y)) in this list. 
Finally after the completion of this operation,the list will contain only one integer,which is the maximum possible integer present in the list,we will return this integer from the list.

I have tried many ways to optimize the statements which are contained inside the body of the loop.My aim is to optimize the code from line 3 to line 5.

```
def rem(n):
    l=list(range(1,n+1))
    for i in range(n-1):
        l.append(l[0]+l[1]+(l[0]*l[1]))
        del l[0:2]
    return (l[0]%1000000007)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do in `rem` because it does not seem to find the `maximum possible integer present in the list` as you mentioned.

Comment: What are you trying to to in lines 4 and 5? Why do you append some values and remove others?

Comment: For most things involving lists; one of the first steps in optimization is to make use of SIMD so that the CPU can do multiple elements of the list in parallel. For python, this means "don't use python" - e.g. use optimized code written in a language like C that's been made to look like a python library. With that in mind, I'd look at something like NumPy to determine if it can do whatever it is you're trying to do.